# MySQL Column that shows order of items

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm new to MySQL procedures and triggers and constraints and I'm wondering how I can set one of my columns to be dependent on another column. For example, I have a table of products and weekly sales similar to:

```
Product_ID    Sales   Ranking
1               13
2               12
3              543
4              435
5               97
```

I want my ranking column to be automatically updated whenever a value in the sales is updated or a new value is inserted (this table will only hold at most 50 products), which means product IDs will come and go. How can I set it so that the Ranking is always an x value such that x represents what position it would be it the product id was ordered by sales DESC?

Product ID is NOT an AI column or Primary Index

Comment: Usually you don't store such values at all. You can just order by sales (desc). If you would need a row number (often it's just as easy to generate that in the consumer of the query, for instance a PHP script), you can query that as well: `SELECT p.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM Products p,  (SELECT @rownum := 0) r ORDER BY Sales DESC`.